# JQuery datatables NPM package throws error when it has more than 10 columns

Tags: angular, npm, datatables

I use datatables NPM Package https://datatables.net/download/npm
in Angular2. When the table has more than 10 columns, it will throw error:

```
> EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Unsupported number of
> argument for <br>pure functions: 11 Error: Unsupported number of
> argument for pure functions: 11 at createPureProxy
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:10955:15) [angular] at
> createCachedLiteralArray
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:20200:101) [angular] at
> _AstToIrVisitor.visitLiteralArray (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:19681:139) [angular] at
> LiteralArray.visit
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:49480:24) [angular] at
> _AstToIrVisitor.visit (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:19828:48) [angular] at
> _AstToIrVisitor.visitLiteralMap (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:19692:43) [angular] at
> LiteralMap.visit (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:49507:24)
> [angular] at ASTWithSource.visit
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:49721:25) [angular] at
> convertPropertyBinding
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:19346:50) [angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96166:165 [angular] at
> Array.forEach (native) [angular] at bindDirectiveInputs
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96162:25) [angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96341:113 [angular] at
> Array.forEach (native) [angular] at ViewBinderVisitor.visitElement
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96339:24) [angular] at
> ElementAst.visit (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11376:24)
> [angular] at visit
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11657:37) [angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11659:42 [angular] at
> Array.forEach (native) [angular] at templateVisitAll
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11658:10) [angular] at
> ViewBinderVisitor.visitElement
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96344:119) [angular] at
> ElementAst.visit (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11376:24)
> [angular] at visit
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11657:37) [angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11659:42 [angular] at
> Array.forEach (native) [angular] at templateVisitAll
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11658:10) [angular] at
> ViewBinderVisitor.visitElement
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96344:119) [angular] at
> ElementAst.visit (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11376:24)
> [angular] at visit
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11657:37) [angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11659:42 [angular] at
> Array.forEach (native) [angular] at templateVisitAll
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11658:10) [angular] at
> ViewBinderVisitor.visitElement
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96344:119) [angular] at
> ElementAst.visit (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11376:24)
> [angular] at visit
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11657:37) [angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11659:42 [angular] at
> Array.forEach (native) [angular] at templateVisitAll
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11658:10) [angular] at
> ViewBinderVisitor.visitElement
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96344:119) [angular] at
> ElementAst.visit (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11376:24)
> [angular] at visit
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11657:37) [angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11659:42 [angular] at
> Array.forEach (native) [angular] at templateVisitAll
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11658:10) [angular] at
> ViewBinderVisitor.visitElement
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96344:119) [angular] at
> ElementAst.visit (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11376:24)
> [angular] at visit
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11657:37) [angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11659:42 [angular] at
> Array.forEach (native) [angular] at templateVisitAll
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11658:10) [angular] at
> ViewBinderVisitor.visitElement
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96344:119) [angular] at
> ElementAst.visit (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11376:24)
> [angular] at visit
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11657:37) [angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11659:42 [angular] at
> Array.forEach (native) [angular] at templateVisitAll
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11658:10) [angular] at
> ViewBinderVisitor.visitElement
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96344:119) [angular] at
> ElementAst.visit (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11376:24)
> [angular] at visit
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11657:37) [angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11659:42 [angular] at
> Array.forEach (native) [angular] at templateVisitAll
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:11658:10) [angular] at
> bindView (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:96290:115)
> [angular] at ViewCompiler.compileComponent
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:23857:94) [angular] at
> JitCompiler._compileTemplate
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:64410:65) [angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:64291:62 [angular] at
> Set.forEach (native) [angular] at JitCompiler._compileComponents
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:64291:19) [angular] at
> createResult (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:64173:19)
> [angular] at Object.onInvoke
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:33229:37) [angular] at
> Zone.run (http://localhost:4201/js/polyfills.bundle.js:17291:43)
> [angular => angular] at
> http://localhost:4201/js/polyfills.bundle.js:17713:57 [angular] at
> Object.onInvokeTask
> (http://localhost:4201/js/vendor.bundle.js:33220:37) [angular] at
> ZoneDelegate.invokeTask
> (http://localhost:4201/js/polyfills.bundle.js:17452:40) [angular] at
> Zone.runTask (http://localhost:4201/js/polyfills.bundle.js:17329:47)
> [<root> => angular] at drainMicroTaskQueue
> (http://localhost:4201/js/polyfills.bundle.js:17611:35) [<root>] Can
> anybody help me how to fix it?
```